# AForge Euclidean Color Filtering - outside color

Tags: c#, aforge

[AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/67fa83b5-dede-8d3a-8d3b-b7a6b9859538.htm) mentions about the *EuclideanColorFiltering Class*:

**"The filter filters pixels, which color is inside/outside of RGB sphere with specified center and radius"**

When I use the filter, I can only filter pixels **outside** the sphere.
How can I control if the filter filters pixels **inside or outside** the sphere?

Comment: Okay, I found the solution: you have to add _filter.FillOutside = true (or false)_

Comment: Want to specify RGB values and get a Bitmap with only that color from an image, all others pixels in to some specified color, can I achieve this using EuclideanColorFiltering, please guide.